# PingFederate multiple Identity providers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, saml-2.0, pingfederate

In my project, I am using PingFederate and want to integrate AD of two separate domains. It is pretty simple to integrate one but wasnt able to find any documentation on how to integrate 2 separate ADs of different domains. Additionally, I want to have IP restrictions as well (like users from IP1 would be authenticated against AD1 and users from IP2 would be authenticated against AD2).

I am using Agent-less integration.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? You can query multiple datastores in the connection, you can authenticate against multiple PCVs, etc... If we're talking solely about authentication, and you're using agentless kit as the IdP adapter, then, integration against those two ADs can be handled directly in your code.

Comment: Hi Andrew, that exactly is my question on how it will be handled in my code. Should I create separate IdP and have logic in my application to call corresponding IdP?

Comment: If you're using the HTML form adapter, you can use Eric U's answer below. It certainly works! However, if you want something a little more "yours" you could build your own IdP Adapter from the agentless kit, and decide how to architect it for YOUR environment. The flexibility is there. You should have a talk with your company's Regional Solutions Architect from Ping for architecture ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Using PingFederate as the Identity PRovider (IdP), you would use an Authentication Selector, specifically the CIDR Selector for IP Restriction.  This inspects the HTTP request for IP ranges using CIDR notation.  The configuration for the Authentication Selector would then define a specific HTML Form Adapter using a specific Password Credential Validator (PCV).  For example, CIDR Selector for IP1 would invoke the HTML1 form adapter that uses PCV to AD1, and then the CIDR Selector for IP2 would invoke HTML2 form adapter that uses PCV to AD2, and so forth.  Authentication selectors have a default if none of the IP ranges match, which could redirect to an error page or goto some default authentication HTML Adapter form.

Comment: Just remember to get the Source IP via X-Forwarded-For if you have a proxy server or similar in front.